# Как использовать дважды значения Repeater (репитера) ACF Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, acf

На странице есть репитер в который загружаются картинки и текст, и ниже на странице эти же  картинки должны повторяться, интересует есть ли возможность вывести дважды  значение репитера, что бы админу не нужно было дважды загружать те же картинки в разные репиторы

```
<div class="block1">
        <?php if( have_rows('repetear') ): while ( have_rows('repetear') ) : the_row(); ?>
        <?php $image = get_sub_field('image_repetear');?>
            <div>
                 <div class="block1__img" style="background-image: url(<?php echo $image['url'] ?>);" > 
 </div>
  <p><?php the_sub_field('text_repetear'); ?></p>
            </div>
            <?php  endwhile; else : endif; ?>
        </div>

<div class="block2">
нужно вывести картинки из предыдущего репитора
 </div>
```

Comment: Так а в чем проблема, выводите так же как в первый раз, только без текста, лишь сами картинки

Comment: vantal пробовала писать <div class="block-2"> <?php if( have_rows('repetear') ): while ( have_rows('repetear') ) : the_row(); ?>
       
            
                 <div class="block1__img" style="background-image: url(<php echo $image['url'] ?>);" 
            </div>
            <?php  endwhile; else : endif; ?> но не работает

Comment: у вас ошибка в `<php echo $image['url'] ?>` -  не хватает знака `?`

Comment: vantal Да, это здесь неверно написала, в коде было верно но не сработало, не хочет выводить повторно репитер

Comment: У вас там есть еще несколько ошибок, просто скопируйте полностью код, и удалите только строку с текстом `<p><?php the_sub_field('text_repetear'); ?></p>`
`

Comment: vantal да, спасибо большое, моя ошибка была в том что я во втором репитере не получала переменную Image, а сразу пыталась ее вывести, еще раз спасибо!

Comment: Если все ок, отметьте мой ответ как решение

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108428/discussion-between-vantal-and-).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<div class="block1">
        <?php if( have_rows('repetear') ): while ( have_rows('repetear') ) : the_row(); ?>
        <?php $image = get_sub_field('image_repetear');?>
            <div>
                 <div class="block1__img" style="padding-bottom: 50px; background-image: url(<?php echo $image['url'] ?>);" > 
 </div>
  <p><?php the_sub_field('text_repetear'); ?></p>
            </div>
            <?php  endwhile; else : endif; ?>
        </div>
<div class="block2">
<?php if( have_rows('repetear') ): while ( have_rows('repetear') ) : the_row(); ?>
        <?php $image = get_sub_field('image_repetear');?>
            <div>
                 <div class="block1__img" style="padding-bottom: 50px; background-image: url(<?php echo $image['url'] ?>);"> 
     </div>
            </div>
            <?php  endwhile; else : endif; ?> </div>
```